# Could not chdir to home directory /gel/usr/me: No such file or directory

Tags: server, ssh

```
┌─╼ [~]
└╼ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 me@server
me@server's password: 
Last login: Sun Jul 11 09:53:39 2021 from 45.73.124.185
Could not chdir to home directory /gel/usr/me: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$ logout
```

I always get this message. Do I have to specify the home directory in the ssh command? If so, how can I do that? Else, how can I fix that error?

The problem might be on the server side. The server is new where I am studying. It might need some adjustment, but it does work very well. Is there a workaround to ssh the server without touching the server configs?

Comment: It looks like `me`'s home directory on `server` is misconfigured.

Comment: @steeldriver Is there a workaround?

Comment: if you know what the correct home directory is then you should be able to use `cd` to get there - but afaik the error itself is something that the server's administrator would need to fix.

Comment: I know where the home directory is. How can I specify it to `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 me@server`?

Comment: You need to fix the server.  The only thing you can do after the ssh me@server is run a command like `ssh me@server 'ls -al'`.  You cannot specify from the client what the home directory is when logging into the server.